# Trying to use Entity Framework with Oracle DB

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, oracle, entity-framework

Hi I am trying to use `Entity-Framework` in asp.net MVC , for that I have installed `Oracle.Managed.DataAccess` version 19.6.0 and `Oracle.Managed.DataAccess.EntityFramework` version 19.6.0
and oracle version 11.2.0 I am able to connect Oracle DB in server explorer but while adding new item in solution not getting any option to connect Oracle DB what is the issue I am not able to identify ,Any idea would be appreciated.
Image[image]

Answer (score 1):

Those are just the Nuget packages to allow your project to connect to Oracle.

I believe you need to add Oracle Developer Tools for Visual Studio to have the options available in the Visual Studio dialogs.

https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/developer-tools/visual-studio/

Comment: i have added oracle developer tool 2015 and added ado.net entity model but while adding view in controller i am getting error unable to find the requested.net framework Data provider.It may not be installed , i tried and search but didnot get resolution for this error

Answer (score 0):

You need to install a Oracle Client and TNSNAMES.ORA

[image: Oracle Client 11.2 Example]

The installation has a component list, if you insall that components (like Oracle developer Tools for visualStudio) it you can add your EF. and then when you finish you only need to add your TNSNAMES in order to create the Entities in VS.